# PhP MySQL: Change Cell Table Colour Based Off Database Entry

Tags: php, mysql, select, printing, html-table

I am currently developing a system where I would like individual cells which are being pulled from a database to change color when  either a check box is clicked.

I am assuming perhaps referencing to the current table and then adding a field where when the check box is click, the value turns to 1 and therefore it will change the color?

I've got as far as thinking an IF statement is needed, but i'm not sure what else.  If there is a simple way, which will fit in the with the following code, that's even better.

```
$query = mysql_query("Select * from list Where id='$id'"); // SQL Query
                $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($count > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        Print "<tr>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['entry'] . "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['title'] . "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['full_name'] . "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['location'] . "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['startdate']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['ipad']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['laptop']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['login']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['frog']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['sims']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['email']. "</td>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['status']. "</td>";

                        Print "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $id_exists = false;
                }
```

If you need any further information I'll be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

which field do you change in your database?
you can use javascript to change the color of your cell when you click on a checkbox.
to change the value in your database you need ajax (no reload of your page)
or pure php. 
One solution is to create a form and on click of your checkbox you can submit the form via javascript. 
in action="index.php" (per example) you can write php code to change the value in your database based on the checkbox values are submitted.

EDIT:

To change color of a cell based on a database entry you can try this per example:

```
<td class="<?php echo($value == 1 ? 'green' : 'red'); ?>"></td>
```

in css you can define you css classes.

```
.green{
  background-color: #f0f;
}

.red{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  If there is a way to do this front end, that's even better.  The only concern I would have is, if using javascript, would it save the changes made or would it be only applicable for that one page?  For example, I want the user to be able to front end edit the entry and then it change on the review entry page

Answer (score 0):

look at my edit.

if you want to change only the color on clicking a checkbox you need javascript.
for updating data you need php code.
you have different options to update data of your database but all of them needs php code.
If you like to update the data witout reloading your page you need ajax.
The easier method is to update the data with a html form.
therefore you have to submit it, and on the destination page (which is definied in this format: `<form action="index.php" ... >`)
you can retrieve you value for the updating field.
Then store it with php in the database, and after it, you can show the html table.

then you can write you if statement to check which color you use in your cell.

Comment: Hmm, thanks again for an example.  However, I can't seem to get it working within the print environment.